# running tests for testrail via the command line

Tags: c#, automated-tests, nunit, testrail

I write automation tests in c# and check via NUnit. Autotests are integrated with TestRail.
If I run tests locally, a test runs aren't performed in TestRail. If I run test from TeamCity, a test run are perfomed in TestRail. In TeamCity tests run with *dotnet test* command.

How can I run tests also what I wrote above but via cmd. For example, Python has *pytest run* and *pytest run testrail*. 
Is there a similar to this but for c#? 
Thanks!